# Cookies/Sessions login system

Tags: php, cookies, session

When a user logins I get him/her's ID and save it in a session var. What I wonder is, is this the way to go? Or should I use cookies? so it automatically login and so on.

```
session_start();


ifcorrectlogin {
$_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($loginQuery, 0, 'user_id');
}
```

how do you authenticate your users?

//Newbie

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Great first question!

Comment: thanks! be ready for more questions ;P

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is the way to go. The session itself is already backed by a cookie to remove you any programming efforts around that. The session (actually, the cookie) will live as long as the user has the browser instance open or until the session times out at the server side because the user didn't visit the site for a certain time (usually around 30 minutes).

On login, just put the obtained `User` in the `$_SESSION`. On every request on the restricted pages you just check if the logged-in `User` is available in the `$_SESSION` and handle the request accordingly, i.e. continue with it or redirect to a login or error page. On logout, just remove the `User` from the `$_SESSION`.

If you want to add a *Remember me on this computer* option, then you'll need to add another cookie yourself which lives longer than the session. You only need to ensure that you generate a long, unique and hard-to-guess value for the cookie, otherwise it's too easy to hack. Look how PHP did it by checking the cookie with the name `phpsessionid` in your webbrowser.

Comment: so if i understand correct if a user wants to be "remembered" i should store a unique string in a cookie and in the db and when the user visits again i check if the cookie exists and if it does exist i compare it with the one in the db?

Comment: Almost good. When a **non-logged-in** user visits, then check in DB for the associated `User` and then "automagically" log it in. I've ever posted an answer which covers exactly that, you may find it useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877242/keep-user-logged-in-when-he-visit-the-same-page-again/1877304#1877304

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can be manipulated very easily. Manage login/logout with Sessions. If you want, you can store the users emailaddress/username in a cookie, and fill the username box for them the next time they visit after the present session has expired.

Comment: The first sentence is a bit paradoxical. PHP maintains the session with help of a cookie. Just ensure that the cookie value is strong enough.

Comment: Balus, I think I see how my answer could be slightly confusing. After reading yours, it would seem to me that we've offered the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to find a session engine so you don't have to deal with the misc. security issues that bite you in the ass if you do the slightest thing wrong. I use django which has a session engine built in. I'm not aware of the other offerings in the field although I would assume most frameworks would have one.

The way they did it in django was by placing a cryptographic hash in the user's cookies that gets updated every page view and saving all other session information in a database on your server to prevent user tampering and security issues.

Answer (score 0):

As [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962271/cookies-sessions-login-system/1962275#1962275) mentions, the `session_`-functions in php are the way to go, your basic idea is sound. But there are still many different realisations, some of them have their pitfalls.
For example, as [Jonathan Samson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962271/cookies-sessions-login-system/1962285#1962285) explains, using cookies can result in security holes.

My PHP is a bit rusty, but I remember that the `session_`-functions can also use session IDs that are encoded in URLs. *(There was also an option to have this automatically added to all local links (as GET) and form targets (as POST). But that was not without risks, either.)* One way to prevent session hijacking by copying the SID is to remember the IP address and compare it for any request that comes with a valid session ID to to IP that sent this request.

As you can see, the underlying method is only the start, there are many more things to consider. The recommendation by [SapphireSun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962271/cookies-sessions-login-system/1962280#1962280) is therefore something to be considered: By using a well tested library, you can gain a good level of security, without using valuable development time for developing your own session system. I would recommend this approach for any system that you want to deploy in the real world.

OTOH, if you want to learn about PHP sessions and security issues, you should definitely do it yourself, if only to understand how *not* to do it ;-)