# What is a Request in Terms of Cookies?

Tags: php, http, cookies

I'm reading up on here about cookies vs sessions. I see that the cookie is sent with every HTTP request, and I want to make sure i understand how the internets work.

Say like I have a page: test.php.  Test.php has 10 script tags on it that go and pull JS scripts () and 5  tags that go pull images.  Is loading Test.php 1 request or 16 requests?

I'm using a cookie to store last 10 visited urls and custom favorite urls.  The favorite URLs can get pretty big.  So I want to make sure that my 1KB of cookie data is sent only 1 time and not 16 times for each request.

Also, I'm using cookies because I already save my permission structure in SESSION, and that can get pretty big too...

Thanks.

Comment: "how the internets work" - Really? - Anyway, you can use Firebug/Dragonfly/etc. to inspect resource requests. Cookies also can be bound to specific paths. Setting up virtual subdomains for static content is another alternative.

Comment: @mario i've read all of the first page of both those links, and my question was not answered.  If I have to dig deeper, than it's too buried.  :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [cookies vs sessions for php application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150930/cookies-vs-sessions-for-php-application) and a bunch more questions on that very topic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20cookies%20vs%20sessions

Comment: @mario yes, how the internet works.  how http works.  Thank you for the tip on firebug.  I dont use FF normally, but I will have to take a look at that.

Comment: I was bemused by the phrasing. Anyway, you could elaborate on your actual cookie data. The expected longevity. That's very relevant for deciding on sessions vs. cookies, or if it can be compacted. I would consider 1 KB in a session store neglectable.  -- Volatile things like last visited urls could well go into the session. While favorites sound like they should have a separate database table per user account.

Comment: I do store that information in favorites in the DB, but instead of loading the urls every page load, I store it in SESSION. I'm still not sure on the overhead required on putting that 1-2kb worth of data in the session vs using a query.

Comment: Well, it amounts to 2MB once you have 1000 concurrent or not logged out users. You could very well compress/uncompress that one session variable. Either way that seems just another database caching method in your case. You'll have to store it *somewhere*..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's 16 requests.

I recommend you only use the `session_id` cookie to identify your visitor (in PHP it's `PHPSESSID` I believe, it will get set automatically if you use `session_start()`). Store the actual session data in a database or some data container of your own. This enables you to put as much in your a session as you want and prevents you from setting and sending too many cookies.

See: [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler), it's a very useful function.

Comment: Just to clarify, Cookies don't do that right?  It is only pulling the session file once on page load, right?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but a session uses a cookie as well (the `PHPSESSID` cookie). The cookie value is just a key though, the actual content of the session is stored on the server.